# Intellij Idea Python unexpected argument

Tags: python, intellij-idea, warnings, intellij-plugin

Why does the following give a warning in IntelliJ:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in range (1,len(my_list)):
    ...
```

I get a warning around "len(my_list)"

If I remove the 1 then the warning goes away. But I want it to skip the first element. I believe the warning is there to say that the length could be zero or one in which case it would not enter the for loop, but that is exactly how I want it to work.

Comment: it is just a warning it won't stop you running the code, I was getting something similar until I updated.

Comment: Yes I know, I can still execute the program with the warning. But I am more interested on why it is giving the warning.

Comment: It must be some minor bug, I would not lose any sleep over it